# How to delete a locally uploaded file on google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to delete a file that I uploaded on Google colab using the following code:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

How to delete the file now? e.g If the file's name is 'sample.jpg' .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this

```
!rm sample.jpg
```

Then check that it is gone with `!ls -al`

Update (nov 2018)
Now you can click to open left pane, browse the files tab, then right click to select and delete a file.

Answer (score 60):

Answer from @Korakot works for a single file and in case, to delete entire folder or subfolders or files

use

`!rm -rf <folder_name>`

Answer (score 10):

To delete a folder which has multiple folders, use:

```
%rm -rf <folder_name>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the menu in Google Collab chose Runtime->Restart all runtimes. This will clear up all your file uploads.

Answer (score 4):

if you are getting edit like,

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

then use

```
%rm -rf folder_name
```

Answer (score 3):

you can see available data or files through !ls

then use !rm for delete

```
> from google.colab import files
> 
> !ls
> 
> !rm data.csv
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8l95.png)

Answer (score 2):

In menu options in Google Colab chose Runtime->Factory reset runtime. This will reset the runtime by deleting all your local file uploads.

Comment: This solution does not exactly suit this problem, since I want to remove just a file and not all of the other files, variables, and processed information. Still, thanks for that!

Comment: In that case,you can simply delete the file by right clicking on the file name and then choose delete option. And then run all the cells,no need of code!

Answer (score 1):

use !rm for deleting FILES

- To remove all files:

  ```
        !rm *
  ```
- To remove a single file:

  ```
        !rm <file_name>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Terminating the sessions under Manage my sessions option is perhaps the easiest way one can do it. There could be downsides of losing other files which you may not want to get rid of and will have to upload them again!

Sometimes, factory reset runtime either after termination of session or without it works as well! Try the combinations and you will find the secret to deleting locally uploaded file (:-D)

Note - If only terminating session does not work, sometimes reloading the webpage again ensures that all locally uploaded files are deleted and you can re-run with freshly uploaded files :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to run time and select delete runtime. This clears all the temporary variables and downloaded data. You can start fresh

**Before clicking:**

[image]

**After clicking:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this command, You can delete any folder in Colab
!rm -rf ./folder_name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any specific type of file, such as a pdf( can be replaced with .txt, .png, .jpeg etc
`!rm -rf /path_of_folder/*.pdf`