# Delete file using variable in Google Colabs

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a file uploaded to google colabs, but when it's uploaded its name is stored in a variable, so how do I use the variable to delete the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a locally uploaded file on google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265978/how-to-delete-a-locally-uploaded-file-on-google-colab)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
!rm {filename}
```

where `filename` is the variable.

Comment: This is not the correct way of doing it, and it probably doesn't work too. You should use `!rm -rf "$filename"` instead.